# How to use std::istreambuf_iterator to intialize a string

Tags: c++, string, iterator

So I'm trying to read a piece of code which goes

```
auto runFile(const std::string &path)
{
    const std::string source = ([&]() {
        std::ifstream file(path);
        return std::string{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};
    })();
}
```

Could someone explain to me exactly what's happening in this line:

```
return std::string{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};
```

I understand that it's supposed to return a string that is made up of a range between the two iterators, but i don't exactly understand what range is being selected here.

If someone could explain to me how istreambuf works in the first place that would be great too!

The simpler an answer the better, as I'm new to c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default-constructed `std::istreambuf_iterator` is known as the end-of-stream iterator.

In other words, the first `iterator` being passed points to a valid `stream` and the second `iterator` being passed, which is default constructed, represents the end of the `stream`.

**cppreference**

> When a valid std::istreambuf_iterator reaches the end of the underlying stream, it becomes equal to the end-of-stream iterator. Dereferencing or incrementing it further invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: So it will iterate through the entire filestream from start to end to construct the string?

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks The `string` iterates over the stream, copying the values and storing them internally. So yes, what you said was correct.